# UnauthorizedAccess directory exception

Tags: vb.net, directory, google-drive-api

I have a project in vb.net , the first step is to choose a directory exist in hard drive and list all files exist in this directory in `gridview`.

The second is compared between the directory selected and a folder chosen in Google drive.

When I find a file exists on the hard drive and not in drive , I list it in `listviewitem` and I upload it in drive

My problem is in uploading to drive, the exception is:

> ```
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : "L'accès au chemin d'accès 'D:\*****' est refusé."
> ```

It means access to path 'D: \ *****' is denied

Here is my code, this in button upload to drive event :

```
Dim ligne As Integer = fs.Items.Count
Dim i As Integer
Dim val As String
For i = 0 To ligne - 1
    val = folder_hard.Item(0, i).Value
    Form1.insert(folder.Text, valeur)
Next
```

`ligne` is for counting number line in my grid
`val` is for index of selected line in `listview`
`insert` is a upload file method

upload file method code :

```
Public Sub insert(nom_dossier As String, nom_fichier As String)
CreateService()
    Dim f As New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
    f.Title = nom_fichier

    Dim reference As New ParentReference()
    f.Parents = New List(Of ParentReference)
    reference.Id = exist(nom_dossier)'test if folder exist or not
    f.Parents.Add(reference)
    f.MimeType = "text/plain , Image / jpeg"
    ' lire le fichier dans un tableau d'octet
    Dim chemin As String = System.IO.Path.Combine("D:\*****")
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(chemin)
    Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim res = Service.Files.Insert(f, stream, f.MimeType).Upload
    MessageBox.Show("Succés d'upload")
End sub
```

Exception occurs in this line:

```
Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(chemin)
```

Comment: It seems you don't have permission to read that file or the files in that directory. It's not a programming issue.

Comment: no , because i verify all permission for all folder in my hard drive , but the same error

Comment: Are you absolutely certain also that the filename is correct .. no spaces after slashes or before the file name and none either side of the dot?

Comment: Just a thought - `Path.Combine` normally takes 2 strings as the parameter - say, the file path and the file name. Yours only has one parameter.

Comment: I change Path.combine to 2 things and the same error

Comment: Is the D drive on the same computer as the program?

Comment: yes , on the same computer

Comment: Have you tried running he program as administrator? If so, I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: i tried to run the program as administrator ..... but same error

Comment: i change bytearray instruction (first , i forgot to add name file with path) 
 Dim bytearray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path + "\" + name_file) ...and it works.... thank you for your help